# Change the color of first letter of all Heading 2 in word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a very large word-document and I want to change the first letter of all Heading 2 to blue.

I already have something, just now I need to change the color of the first letter.

How to do this?

```
Public Sub H2ChangeColor()
    Dim p As Paragraph

    With ActiveDocument
        For Each p In .Paragraphs
            If p.Style = "Heading 2" Then
                p.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
            End If
        Next p
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved it. Not all headings are working though, but I guess that problem lies somewhere else.

```
Public Sub H2ChangeColor()
    Dim p As Paragraph

    With ActiveDocument
    For Each p In .Paragraphs
    If p.Style = "Heading 2" Then
        p.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack
        p.Range.Characters(1).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
    End If
    Next p
    End With
End Sub
```